# Nested PopupWindows: Exception

Tags: android, exception, popupwindow

My app has a PopupWindow for the creation of an entry. In this popup, it makes use of an AutoCompleteTextView - however, when showDropDown() is called, the following exception is thrown:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@418400f0 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

It seems to have to do with the AutoCompleteTextView being inside a PopupWindow (because before I put it in there it worked), causing two PopupWindows to exist (nested).

Do you know of a workaround for this?

Comment: Please share your code. also try (getApplicationContext()) if you are using application context.

Comment: It's too much code to make sense here. Context is not involved here. The problem seems to be that AutoCompleteView needs a Window from the Activity, but it does not get it because PopupWindow is its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Nested Popupwindow are having issue as you explained.. but this behavior can be achieved using custom dialogs..
I answered [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15766097/1677824)..